# Web scraper with Python (BeautifulSoup 4) doesn't work

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The problem is I have no idea how do it. I'm trying to print a

with the class .first-text and it prints the whole HTML. How can I print it, using BeatifulSoup 4?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("http://lifehacker.com/this-video-explains-how-to-survive-a-free-falling-eleva-1738366697").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
p = soup.p
meow = soup.find(p['class'] == "first-text")
if meow:
    print(meow)
else:
    print(404)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing a logical expression in the find function, the call should look something likes this.

```
meow = soup.find('p', class="first-text")
```

Generally you should look in the documentation for such info, you find a great set of examples and description of how to use it